# Trouble making POST request from c# [.NET]

Tags: c#, .net

We have a created an `API` for the application which takes the image via `POST` request process it and sends the result in `JSON` format.

We tried calling API from different sources like python, postman app, c#. We can successfully call end point using `python` and `postman` app but with `c#` getting error

[image]

**c# code [Not working]**

```
byte[] img_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"file_path");
string url_ep = "http://ip:port/get";

Dictionary<string, byte[]> fl_image = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
fl_image.Add("image", img_data);

string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fl_image);

var dataToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url_ep);

request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = dataToSend.Length;
request.Method = "POST";

request.GetRequestStream().Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
var response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
```

**python code [working]**

```
import requests

url = 'http://ip:port/get'

fl_image = {'image': open('file_path', 'rb')}

res = requests.post(url, files=fl_image)
print(res.json())
```

**API Endpoint**

```
from flask import Flask, request
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

@app.route('/get', methods = ['POST'])
def get_image():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        file = request.files['image']

        # Read file
        f = file.read()
        # convert string of image data to uint8
        f1 = np.fromstring(f, np.uint8)
        # decode image
        f2 = cv.imdecode(f1,cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: There is no problem in python side I think error happen because of the way you calling api from c# side.

Comment: @DinushaDilanka Is it some encoding issue, that API end doesn't understand received data format or its Visual Studio problem.

Comment: You can test that by doing this, first you can save your image data where your python api has been deployed then read from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the way you are posting data from C#. The most relevant one is that you are trying to post a file **as a JSON object**, with file contents as string.

This cannot work: your python server is clearly expecting `multipart/form-data` as content-type.

I also strongly recommend you to use `HttpClient` and not the old `HttpWebRequest` class to send HTTP Requests.

```
var filePath = @"file_path";
var url = "http://ip:port/get";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    var imageContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

    // NOTE: the line below is not required, but useful when you know the media type
    imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");

    content.Add(imageContent, "image", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

    var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // do what you need with the response
}
```

Other minor issues:

- Do not read the entire file in memory (using `File.ReadAllBytes`), but open a stream for reading instead.
- Use `async`/`await` when possible, do not block on `async` code (do not use `.Result`, `.Wait()` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on `Task` or `Task<T>`)
- Always call `Dispose()` on `IDisposable` objects when you have finished using them (wrapping them inside a `using` block)

Answer (score -1):

You need to dispose the connections

```
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Hope this helps

Or try using HttpClient for .net within the using block